# Changing dojo.declare to a "native Javascript class decleration"

Tags: javascript, class, dojo, declaration

I have this code:

```
dojo.declare("dh.medview.Viewport", null, {
    someMember: null;
    someFunction: function() {
    }
});
```

How can I transform this code to get an pure "JS class" decleration?

Comment: Javascript doesn't have classes, so there's no such thing as a pure JS class declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// create namespace
dh = dh || {};
dh.medview = dh.medview || {};

// constructor:
dh.medview.Viewport = function() {
    // yours is empty
};

// setup properties of the prototype
var proto = dh.medview.Viewport.prototype;
proto.someMember = null;
proto.someFunction = function() {…};
```

Comment: And how to create a new medview instance ? ....
this is not working: `someVar = new dh.medview.MedView({});`

Comment: You want `new dh.medview.Viewport;` I guess

Comment: And what if you have two different "classes" in one file? Let's say dh.medview.Viewer!

Comment: It's completely equivalent. Only you need to create the namespace object just once per file.